# An variable value isn't being set while code running. In code as follows

Tags: c#, variables, null, set

There is an issue in the code that follows.

I can't understand why `WorkshopIsPainted` is always `null` despite the fact that `workshop.Painted` is `true` or `false`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form  
{  
    public bool?  WorkshopIsPainted;

    public Form1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
    }     

    private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!workshop.painted)
        {
            WorkshopIsPainted = workshop.Painted;
        }
        else return;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your `null` problem, why you declare `bool?  WorkshopIsPainted`? - You know that `bool?` is a `nullable` `bool`? - Have a read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: Conventional bool is always false while initializing. I don't need neither true nor false while Form initializing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to be like

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WorkshopIsPainted = workshop.Painted;
  return;
}
```

Comment: Really? All events  are being created inside Form constructor by default.

Comment: @Msorich, you have the handler inside constructor and not the event declaration

Comment: ОК. I'll try that you suggested. But timer event handler was created inside by default. What's difference inside/ outside of constructor?

Comment: I'm sorry! I've screwed up with a code! Now is correct. So uncomfortable UI of forum. The question is still open.

Comment: ОК.This code has assigned false while workshop.Painted is true. How to assign true? And why previous code wasn't working?

Comment: @Msorich cause you had an if condition and on else you were not assigning. you don't need that if condition at all. see edit again

Comment: The last code has assigned true, but  WorkshopIsPainted has remained true when I forced workshop.Painted to false! Is timer_tick cycle not working?